# Can only get my data scraper to pull data from one listing, whenever i build a for loop it gives an error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data of all the sold listings on Ebay for a particular item. I figured out how to grab the first item on the page but when I try to make a for loop to grab all the subsequent posts, it fails

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=charmander%201st%20edition%20psa%2010&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').find('w-root') 
#This gives the HTML of the page that includes all the listings


item = soup.li 
#each specific item is in an li tag and this variable grabs the first item that was sold 

title = item.h3.a.text

print(title)

price = item.span.text

print(price)

#correctly prints out the Title and price of the first listing
```

that part works fine, its just when i try and do a for loop to grab all the other listings I get an error.

I've tried a few different things but here is an example:

```
for li in soup:

    title = li

    print(title)

#this gives me the tags for each listing but when i try and go deeper into the tags like...

for li in soup:

    title = li.h3.a.text  #similar to how i originally grabbed the first item

    print(title)

it prints out: "AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'h3'"
```

and similarly for the price variable. I cant even do `li.prettify()` without getting this error.

If i am using a bad approach or anyone knows how to fix this i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, your getting this error because not all li will have `<a>` tag encapsulated within a `<h3>` tag

```
for li in soup:
    try:
        title = li.h3.a.text
    except:
        continue
    print(title)
```

**EDIT**

Using find_all() can be used to get all items and its prices.You can loop through items and prices. I already tried to print the first 5 items, as you can see

```
items= soup.find_all('h3',class_='lvtitle')
price= soup.find_all('li',class_='lvprice prc')
for i in range(5):
    print items[i].text,price[i].text
```

**Output**

> 1st Edition Pokemon Psa 10 Charmander Base Set Shadowless 46/102, New Case!
>   $95.00
>
> Pokemon 1st Edition Base Set CHARMANDER Shadowless #46 PSA 10 GEM Mint
>   $111.00
>
> Pokemon 1st Edition Base Set CHARMANDER Shadowless #46 PSA 10 GEM Mint
>   $114.95 Was: Previous Price $121.00
>
> Pokemon PSA 10 GEM MINT 1st Edition Shadowless Charmander - English Base Set
>   $119.99
>
> Pokemon PSA 10 - Charizard, Charmeleon, + Charmander - POKEKYUN 1st Edition $60.00

Comment: okay thanks! that makes a lot of sense to me. I am still learning the basics on coding but I feel like I should have been able to consider trying this.

However, when i run this code, it only prints the first title then the program stops. its not parsing through all of the titles like i want, any idea why?

Comment: hmm that didnt seem to work either. when i write 

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').find('w-root')

instead of find('w-root') is there any way i can use 'ul' class_= ListVIewInner?

Comment: @Gmuersch I have added a code in my answer that can get all items ans prices. Please do try it out